# VUEJS Wrap Element in a link

Tags: vue.js

I would like to wrap an element with a link **ONLY if a link** is available:

Normally I would use:

```html
    <a v-if="url" href="url">
      <some-content></some-content>
    </a>
    <some-content v-else></some-content>
```

BUT this leads to a lot of code duplication, especially if some-content is complex.

I tried to use it like this:

```html
    <wrap-link :url="url">
      <some-content></some-content>
    </wrap-link>
```

Where **wrap-link** is like the following, but I can't get rid of the "span" in the `v-else` part.

```html
    <template>
      <a v-if="url" :href="url">
        <slot></slot>
      </a>
      <span v-else>
        <slot></slot>
      </span>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      props: {
        url: { type: String, default: '' },
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Vue 3

Vue 3 allows multiple root nodes, so putting the `v-else` directive directly on the `<slot>` in the root is allowed:

```html
<template>
  <a v-if="url" :href="url">
    <slot></slot>
  </a>
  <slot v-else></slot>
</template>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-wrap-link)

#### Vue 2 or Vue 3

In either version of Vue, you could use a [`<component>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#component) whose properties are computed based on `url`:

```html
<template>
  <component :is="component" v-bind="props">
    <slot></slot>
  </component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    url: { type: String, default: '' }
  },
  computed: {
    component() {
      return this.url ? 'a' : 'slot'
    },
    props() {
      return this.url ? { href: this.url } : null
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/link-wrapper-in-vue-2-kf25c?file=/src/App.vue)